# "Known not to ..." or "Known to not ..."

Tags: word-order, negation, infinitives

Which one of the following word orders is correct:

> This program is known not to work correctly.

or

> This program is known to not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

They are both acceptable.

There is a common notion that it is incorrect to "split an infinitive", but this appears to have been invented by authors of Grammar Handbooks. Following this rule, *known not to work* would be preferred. But English speakers will understand eiher version without difficulty.

Comment: While there may be **some** truth in the "grammar book" theory, incidence of the "split infinitive" does seem to be quite low up to 1900. Ngrams for [to not _VERB_](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+not+_VERB_&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) and [to _ADV_ _VERB_](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+_ADV_+_VERB_&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) show a dip around 1920 (grammar books?) and a big rise after 1960 (eschewal of grammar books?) but a low incidence up to 1900 (normal practice?)

Comment: [..much later] It was my understanding that the grammar book fad was earlier, 17-18th centuries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perhaps counter-intuitive. With

> The man was advised to not wear red.

the order seems logical, and the sentence sounds reasonable, if the last three words are given moderate stress. However,

> The man was advised not to wear red.

is by far the more idiomatic (usually used) variant.

I've given a different pair of examples; I think that, in some cases, the more logical version is bordering on unacceptable because it would sound so strange.

> He was believed to not be the former Nazi leader.